# Angular.js Directive on condition...rather than hard code in html

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular.js.... not sure how to implement this....

I have a seperate service and directive that calls out to a api and if that api returns a json that has the word `success` in it, then run a separate directive that returns a function that creates and modifies elements.

The problem is that the separate directive would have to be hard coded into the html...such as `<directive blah blah></directive>`. I can't hard code it because...it is conditional... the service api call may not return `success`.

Since element creation and modification has to go into directives for conventions(and possibly even scope...not sure if I will modify that yet or not)...and this is dynamic/conditional....can I call the directive as a function in a controller or service? Rather than hard code it into the html? If not, what other way could I do this?

Comment: why not `ng-if`, you can write the html of both and then `<directive1 ng-if="success"></directive1> <directive2 ng-if="!success"></directive2>`

Comment: Read about compile/link steps for directives

Comment: I thought about that but...the return json value isn't really going to the html.

Comment: You might have to use `$compile` service to compile a directive on the fly in a controller.